# Retrieve all records with LIMIT in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query;

```
SELECT records FROM users
LIMIT 1
```

One record will be retrieved. Suppose I want to retrieve all records but still use the keyword LIMIT. Can I do something like this?

```
SELECT records FROM users
LIMIT ALL
```

Comment: why you want do that? if you want all records remove the `LIMIT`

Comment: Often this is done with a large number . . . `LIMIT 999999999`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

> SELECT records FROM users

Do not use LIMIT at all

Or if it is required to use LIMIT , use a very high number

> SELECT records FROM users LIMIT 999999999999

Answer (score 2):

You have to just make up a ridiculous number and limit it by that.

E.g. `SELECT records FROM users LIMIT 18446744073709551615` if you really want to keep the limit clause. This is similar to using offset to infinite amount.

Comment: May I ask what is the largest number acceptable in this context?

Comment: I used 18446744073709551615 as it's the max for `bigint` in mysql and generally you'll have an auto_incrementing column. Any higher and you won't be able to store rows with an AI id as far as I know.

Comment: I guess -1^1 is bit more readable (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

According to mysql doc you are supposed to use a very large number.
`SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`

Terrible solution, if you ask me, but its from the mysql documentation
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4651990

Comment: Why are you using an offset?

Comment: I got that line from their website. I pasted the link there.

Comment: You should probably understand the syntax first before you post it as an answer though. In general cases, you won't need LIMIT with a very high number as you would just not have the clause, although the OP wants it. What you have posted is a way to grab all rows AFTER line 95 which isn't what was asked for in the original post. The syntax for the query you posted is `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME LIMIT OFFSET,AMOUNT_OF_ROWS`. In this case, no offset is needed.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve all data then just use

select * from tbl;